how to draw circle touching two other circles near intersection
I want to draw a circle with a given radius so that it touches two other bigger circles near their intersection. I am using the tkz-euclide package but could not figure out this case.
The code below creates the two circles and guesses the point for the 3rd circle.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\ra}{39}
\newcommand{\thick}{ 6 }  
\newcommand{\fa}{3} 
\newcommand{\fb}{3} 
\newcommand{\bias}{1} 

% ignore that, it's just copy-paste
\FPeval{\y}{2*\ra/2.618}
\FPeval{\f}{ (2*\ra )- (\y)  }
\FPeval{\rasmall}{\ra - \thick}
\FPeval{\faa}{ \f - \fa  +\bias}
\FPeval{\fbb}{ \fb - \bias }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2]
\tkzDefPoint(\fa - \bias,-\fb +\bias){A}    %center of circle 1
\tkzDefPoint(\f, 0){B}                      %center of circle 2
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\rasmall)(B,\ra) \tkzGetPoints{M1}{N1} 
\begin{scope}
\tkzClipCircle(A,M1)
% \tkzFillCircle[color=green!50,opacity=.5](B,M1)
\end{scope}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[M1](192:6.4){BB}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](A,\rasmall)    %draw circle 1 centered at A with radius 1
\tkzDrawCircle[R](B,\ra)         %draw circle 1 centered at A with radius 1
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](M1,N1)%Draw points
\tkzDrawCircle[color=orange,R](BB,4) %

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Guessing is no construction, which should come before coding. // How would you construct such a thing?

That is the question. I think there is a line (circle?) with all the possible circles touching both bigger circles but I don't know how to calculate that line.

That's a question for the math forum, isn't it?

The construction is simple if the radius of the circles are known: find the intersection of the circle with same center as circle 1 but radius r1-r3 and same center as circle 2 on the right but withe radius r2+r3, which will be the center of the 3rd circle

Your version of tkz-euclide is obsolete. \tkzDrawCircle[R] is no longer valid. First define the circle with \tkzDefCircle[R]{center,r} and \tkzGetPoint{pt} to obtain a point on the circle, then draw \tkzDrawCircle{center,pt}.

I don't have much time but I'll make another proposal later.
Your version of tkz-euclide is obsolete because it no longer compiles with the most recent version. tkzDrawCircle[R] no longer exists with this option see code below.
A) With old version
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\ra}{39}
\newcommand{\thick}{ 6 }  
\newcommand{\fa}{3} 
\newcommand{\fb}{3} 
\newcommand{\bias}{1} 

% ignore that, it's just copy-paste
\FPeval{\y}{2*\ra/2.618}
\FPeval{\f}{ (2*\ra )- (\y)  }
\FPeval{\rasmall}{\ra - \thick}
\FPeval{\faa}{ \f - \fa  +\bias}
\FPeval{\fbb}{ \fb - \bias }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2]
\tkzDefPoint(\fa - \bias,-\fb +\bias){A}    %center of circle 1
\tkzDefPoint(\f, 0){B}                      %center of circle 2
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\rasmall)(B,\ra) \tkzGetPoints{M1}{N1} 
\begin{scope}
\tkzClipCircle(A,M1)
\end{scope}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[M1](192:6.4){BB}
\tkzDefCircle[R](A,\rasmall)  \tkzGetPoint{a}  %draw circle 1 centered at A with radius 1
\tkzDefCircle[R](B,\ra)  \tkzGetPoint{b}        %draw circle 1 centered at A with radius 1
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](M1,N1)%Draw points
\tkzDrawCircles[](A,a B,b)
\FPeval{\raa}{ \rasmall-4}
\FPeval{\rbb}{ \ra+4 }
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\raa)(B,\rbb) \tkzGetPoints{P1}{Q1} 
\tkzDefCircle[R](P1,4)  \tkzGetPoint{c}   %
\tkzDrawCircle[orange](P1,c)
\tkzLabelPoints(P1,Q1) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

B) With tkz-euclide v5.10 or >= 5
You don't need fp because the new version uses xfp (see in the code edef\raa{\fpeval{\ra - \r}}).
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\ra{4} 
\def\rb{6}
\def\r{.5}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/2/B}
\tkzDefCircle[R](A,\ra)\tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzDefCircle[R](B,\rb) \tkzGetPoint{b}
\tkzInterCC(A,a)(B,b) \tkzGetPoints{E}{F} 
\edef\raa{\fpeval{\ra - \r}}
\edef\rbb{\fpeval{\rb + \r}}
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\raa)(B,\rbb) \tkzGetPoints{P}{Q} 
\tkzDefCircle[R](P,\r)  \tkzGetPoint{c} 
\tkzDrawCircles[cyan](A,a B,b)
\tkzDrawCircles[purple](A,P B,P)
\tkzDrawCircle[orange](P,c)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](E,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

C) New version upgraded
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\ra{4} 
\def\rb{6}
\def\r{.5}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/2/B}
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\ra)(B,\rb) \tkzGetPoints{E}{F} 
\edef\raa{\fpeval{\ra - \r}}
\edef\rbb{\fpeval{\rb + \r}}
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\raa)(B,\rbb) \tkzGetPoints{P}{Q} 
\tkzDefCircle[R](P,\r)  \tkzGetPoint{c} 
\tkzDrawCircles[cyan](A,E B,E)
\tkzDrawCircles[purple](A,P B,P)
\tkzDrawCircle[orange](P,c)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](E,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

D) version with tkz-elements and tkz-euclide option mini
Compilation must be done with lualatex
Calculations are easier than with TeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
z.A = point : new (0,0)
z.B = point : new (5,2)
ra = 4
rb = 6
r = .5
C.A = circle : radius (z.A,ra)
C.B = circle : radius (z.B,rb)
z.E = intersection (C.A,C.B)
C.AA = circle : radius (z.A,ra-r)
C.BB = circle : radius (z.B,rb+r)
z.P = intersection (C.AA,C.BB)
C.P = circle : radius (z.P,r)
z.X = C.P.through
\end{tkzelements}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawCircles[cyan](A,E B,E)
\tkzDrawCircles[purple](A,P B,P)
\tkzDrawCircle[orange](P,X)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Well done! The geometric construction is as simple as it is brilliant!

I'm impressed and overwhelmed by the answers. Unfortunately and quite embarrassingly, none are working on my ubuntu (22.04) system, neither with lualatex nor with pdflatex.  errors here: https://pastebin.com/Qc4L2bV5

That's a problem related to Ubuntu and/or to your LaTeX installation. E.g. I interchanged code between Ubuntu and Windows without pain.

@ThierryBlanc I saw somewhere the problems related to a TeX installation with Ubuntu. It would probably be interesting to ask a question specific to Ubuntu-related problems. What is your version of tkz-euclide? I imagine it's possible to get a recent version on CTAN and install it in a personal texmf.

@AlainMatthes I use the default ubuntu installation of texlive-full plus some more packages. tkz-euclide is 4.03. I could not find a way to force ubuntu to upgrade. tkz-elements are not installed and I added the sty file manually to the directory where the tex file is located. I also added the tkz-elements folder (content of latex-dir) there and now I get  LaTeX Error: File `tkz-draw-eu-points.tex' not found.

Created a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717318/how-to-use-tkz-euclide-with-standard-ubutu-installation

After I downloaded tkz-elements and pasted the stuff in the same directory as the tex-file (and symlinking to all files in the directories), A, B and C compile, pdflatex and lualatex. But D still doesn't (lualatex).

Just to show the construction method in MetaPost. Sorry for I'm not good at using TiKz.
beginfig(1);
  d1 = 4cm;
  d2 = 5cm;
  d3 = 1cm;
  draw fullcircle scaled d1 shifted (10, 50);
  draw fullcircle scaled d2;
  path c[];
  c1 = fullcircle scaled (d1-d3) shifted (10, 50);
  c2 = fullcircle scaled (d2+d3);
  draw c1 withcolor .8white;
  draw c2 withcolor .8white;
  draw fullcircle scaled d3 shifted (c1 intersectionpoint c2) withcolor .4 white;;
endfig;



An approach using the experimental l3draw package (showing all possible placements of a circle with a specific radius to touch two other intersecting circles):
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi=drawing]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \TwoAndOneCircle } { O{1} m m m m O{1} m } {
    \draw_begin:
    
        \draw_path_circle:nn {#2} {#3}
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { draw }
    
        \draw_path_circle:nn {#4} {#5}
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { draw }
    
        \draw_path_circle:nn { 
            \int_case:nn {#1} {
                {1} {
                    \draw_point_intersect_circles:nnnnn 
                        {#2} { #3 + #7 } {#4} { #5 + #7 } {#6}
                }
                {2} {
                    \draw_point_intersect_circles:nnnnn 
                        {#2} { #3 + #7 } {#4} { #5 - #7 } {#6}
                }
                {3} {
                    \draw_point_intersect_circles:nnnnn 
                        {#2} { #3 - #7 } {#4} { #5 + #7 } {#6}
                }
                {4} {
                    \draw_point_intersect_circles:nnnnn 
                        {#2} { #3 - #7 } {#4} { #5 - #7 } {#6}
                }
            }
            
        } {#7}    
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { draw }
        
    \draw_end:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{drawing}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn {2} {
    \int_step_inline:nn {4} {
        \begin{drawing}
            \TwoAndOneCircle[##1]{1cm,4cm}{7cm}{0cm,0cm}{5cm}[#1]{1cm}
        \end{drawing}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

 
The first argument takes an integer between 1 and 4 which selects where the third circle should touch the other two circles as follows:

1: first circle outside, second circle outside (default)
2: first circle outside, second circle inside
3: first circle inside, second circle outside
4: first circle inside, second circle inside

The second arguments takes the coordinate of the first circle (as (x,y) tuple with or without surrounding parenthesis). The third argument takes the radius of the first circle.
The fourth arguments takes the coordinate of the second circle (as (x,y) tuple with or without surrounding parenthesis). The fifth argument takes the radius of the second circle.
The sixth argument selects the intersection near which the third circle should touch the other two. Due to logic, only 1 or 2 are valid here (1 is default).
The last argument takes the radius of the third circle.
The command does not test whether there the third circle can actually touch the other two given the arguments. An error will be issued in such a case.

But you could also create a TikZ solution using a \pic using the same logic:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifTwoandonecircleCircleOneInside
\newif\ifTwoandonecircleCircleTwoInside

\tikzset{
    pics/two and one circle/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{two and one circle/.cd, #1}
            \coordinate (circle one at) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle one at});
            \coordinate (circle two at) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle two at});
            \draw[pic actions, two and one circle/circle one] 
                (circle one at)
                circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle one radius}];
            \draw[pic actions, two and one circle/circle two] 
                (circle two at)
                circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle two radius}];
            \pgfpointintersectionofcircles{
                    \pgfpointanchor{circle one at}{center}
                }{
                    \pgfpointanchor{circle two at}{center}
                }{
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle one radius} 
                    \ifTwoandonecircleCircleOneInside
                        - \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle three radius} 
                    \else
                        + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle three radius} 
                    \fi
                }{
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle two radius}
                    \ifTwoandonecircleCircleTwoInside
                        - \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle three radius} 
                    \else
                        + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle three radius} 
                    \fi
                }{
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/intersection}
                }
            \pgfgetlastxy{\TwoandonecircleCircleThreeX}{\TwoandonecircleCircleThreeY}
            \draw[pic actions, two and one circle/circle three]
                (\TwoandonecircleCircleThreeX,\TwoandonecircleCircleThreeY) 
                circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/two and one circle/circle three radius}];
            
        }
    },
    two and one circle/circle one at/.initial={0,0},
    two and one circle/circle one radius/.initial={1cm},
    two and one circle/circle one/.style={},
    two and one circle/circle two at/.initial={1,0},
    two and one circle/circle two radius/.initial={1cm},
    two and one circle/circle two/.style={},
    two and one circle/circle three radius/.initial={0.25cm},
    two and one circle/circle three/.style={},
    two and one circle/inside circle one/.is if=TwoandonecircleCircleOneInside,
    two and one circle/inside circle one=false,
    two and one circle/inside circle two/.is if=TwoandonecircleCircleTwoInside,
    two and one circle/inside circle two=false,
    two and one circle/intersection/.initial={1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic {
        two and one circle={
            circle three/.style={red}, 
            intersection=2, 
            inside circle one
        }
    };

    \pic[thick] at (0,-2) {
        two and one circle={
            circle one/.style={blue, dashed}, 
            circle three/.style={magenta}, 
            circle one radius=0.75cm,
            circle two at={1,-0.5},
            circle three radius=0.5cm,
            inside circle two
        }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



works out of the box. Thank you.

@ThierryBlanc It is not TikkZ, so you can't style it with TikZ. But you could actually use the same logic to construct a TikZ pic ...

@ThierryBlanc I added a solution using a \pic based on the same logic

According to Alain Matthes' very nice answer, hoping that the code will be compilable on the system of Thierry Blanc who asked the question.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\ra{4} 
\def\rb{6}
\def\r{.5}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,2);
\draw[name path=cercle A,cyan](A) circle[radius=\ra];
\draw[name path=cercle B,cyan](B) circle[radius=\rb];
\path[name intersections={of=cercle A and cercle B,by={E,F}}];
\pgfmathsetmacro\raa{\ra - \r}
\pgfmathsetmacro\rbb{\rb + \r}
% replace the `draw=purple` parameter below with `overlay` to hide the purple circles and make the image bounding box no larger than it needs to be, as recommended by @Qrrbrbirlbel. 
\path[name path=cercle A',draw=purple](A) circle[radius=\raa];
\path[name path=cercle B',draw=purple](B) circle[radius=\rbb];
\path[name intersections={of=cercle A' and cercle B',by={P,Q}}];
\draw[orange](P) circle[radius=\r];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I'd suggest using overlay on the purple paths if they aren't drawn. Otherwise the picture's bounding box gets bigger than it needs to be.

I didn't know that overlay could ignore bounding boxes. It's really handy for small figures.

overlay is the key version of the pgfinterruptboundingbox environment – kind of.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Many thanks, I've updated the answer.

For example of usability, I wrote two commands for the "two circles and one adjacent circle" with the following options:

show all 8 circles to 2 given circles (\touchingCircleShow)
get center points of specific circles of these 8 (always in pairs of P and Q)
get coordinates of touching points of the adjacent circles with one of the two circles (PM,PN,QM,QN)

E.g. `\touchingCircleShow{}{A}{\ra}{D}{\rd}{\r} shows all the 8 adjacent circles
\touchingCircleCoord{S}{A}{\ra}{D}{\rd}{\r}` returns the coordinates to create the circles or an arc. See image.

The code could probably be substantially improved...
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\newcommand\touchingCircleShow[6]{%
\foreach \n in {N,W,S,E}{
    \touchingCircleCoord{\n}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
    \draw[color=red](P) circle[radius=#6] node[center] () {P-\n} ;
    \draw[color=red](Q) circle[radius=#6] node[center] () {Q-\n} ; 
    }
}

\newcommand\touchingCircleCoord[6]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{N}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\raa{#3 +#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rbb{#5 +#6}
        }{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\raa{#3 +#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rbb{#5 -#6}      
        }{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{W}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\raa{#3 -#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rbb{#5 +#6}    
        }{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\raa{#3 -#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rbb{#5 -#6}      
        }{}
        %
%     \tkzInterCC[R](#2,\raa)(#4,\rbb) \tkzGetPoints{P}{Q}  
%     \tkzInterCC[](#2,#3)(P,#6) \tkzGetPoint{PM}    
%     \tkzInterCC[](#4,#5)(P,#6) \tkzGetPoint{PN}
%     \tkzInterCC[](#2,#3)(Q,#6) \tkzGetPoint{QM}
%     \tkzInterCC[](#4,#5)(Q,#6) \tkzGetPoint{QN}
    \path[name path=ciA ,](#2) circle[radius=\raa];
    \path[name path=ciB ,](#4) circle[radius=\rbb];
    \path[name intersections={of=ciA and ciB , by={P,Q}}];
%    
    \path[name path=ciC ](#2)  circle[radius=#3];        
    \path[name path=ciD ](#4)  circle[radius=#5];
    \path[name path=ciSm1](P)   circle[radius=#6];
    \path[name path=ciSm2](Q)   circle[radius=#6];
%   
    \path[name intersections={of=ciC and ciSm1 , by={PM}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=ciD and ciSm1 , by={PN}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=ciC and ciSm2 , by={QM}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=ciD and ciSm2 , by={QN}}];
}

\def\ra{75} 
\def\rd{65}
\def\r{12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ scale = 0.2]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (D) at (20,30 );
\draw[name path=cA,cyan](A) circle[radius=\ra];
\draw[name path=cD,cyan](D) circle[radius=\rd];

\touchingCircleShow{}{A}{\ra}{D}{\rd}{\r}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ scale = 0.2]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (D) at (20,30 );
\draw[name path=cA,cyan](A) circle[radius=\ra];
\draw[name path=cD,cyan](D) circle[radius=\rd];

% get coordinates for touching circle 
% #1 NWST for directions (north, east, west, south)
% #2 #3 : center, radius of first cirle
% #4 #5 : center, radius of 2nd circle
% #6 radius adjacend circle 
%
% returns points P and Q, centres of adjacend circles, PM/PN and QM/QN touching points  
%
\touchingCircleCoord{S}{A}{\ra}{D}{\rd}{\r}
%  classic adjacend circles (green and cyan)
\draw[green] (P) circle[radius=\r];
\draw[yellow](Q) circle[radius=\r];
% 
\touchingCircleCoord{W}{A}{\ra}{D}{\rd}{\r}
%  using touching points for arc
\tkzDrawArc[R with nodes,color=cyan](P,\r)(PN,PM);
\tkzDrawArc[R with nodes,color=cyan](Q,\r)(QM,QN);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

