how to quickly install packages from CTAN locally in standard ubuntu installation
Ubuntu (22.04) with texlive-full installation uses tkz-euclide 4.03
Even after manually installing additonal packages I get plenty of errors.
Which packages should I install and what to install where so that tkz-euclide compiles flawlessly with the newest version in an out of the box texlive environment (apt install  texlive-full) in Ubuntu?
(The answer might well be usable for other cases where the system uses older versions of packages.)
This is the texfile, lualatex (the other 3 files magically work now!?)
documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}


\begin{document}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
z.A = point : new (0,0)
z.B = point : new (5,2)
ra = 4
rb = 6
r = .5
C.A = circle : radius (z.A,ra)
C.B = circle : radius (z.B,rb)
z.E = intersection (C.A,C.B)
C.AA = circle : radius (z.A,ra-r)
C.BB = circle : radius (z.B,rb+r)
z.P = intersection (C.AA,C.BB)
C.P = circle : radius (z.P,r)
z.X = C.P.through
\end{tkzelements}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawCircles[cyan](A,E B,E)
\tkzDrawCircles[purple](A,P B,P)
\tkzDrawCircle[orange](P,X)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=orange, fill=orange](E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Errors:
! Package pgf Error: No shape named `E' is known.
...


Please include a short test file in your question and show which errors you get.

I have the same version (tkz-euclide 4.03 installed with apt install texlive-full on Ubuntu 22.04) but it works without any problems, I tried to run the example on page 21 of the manual and that gives the expected output. So, as samcarter suggested, you need to be more specific and edit into your question which code you use and which errors you get.

The helper package tkz-elements is not in texlive-full, how did you install it? When I just download the .sty and the .lua files from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-elements then it compiles without errors and creates the expected output.


tkz-euclide is old, how to upgrade? 2. I downloaded the package from ctan and then guesswork started. Where to place the files, what command to run, etc. I ended up just pasting the latex dir to the tex-file and then I symlinked to all files in this dir so that lualatex has "direct access". I just could not find an easy installation manual for ubuntu (22.04)



you don't need to upgrade necessarily, as the code you provided runs fine with version 4.03. 2. there are different ways to install a package manually (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) but the easiest is usually to download the files and copy them into the same directory where your document is, then LaTeX will automatically find the package when you compile this document.


I installed tkz-euclide and tkz-elements locally and it lualatex uses version (2024/04/19 5.10c, according \listfiles output option), but I still get the 11 errors: pfg Error: No shape 'E' is known \tkzDrawCircles ...

Now I succeeded!
The nasty thing is that tex does not search recursively. All files from the CTAN archive must be in the same directory as the tex-file to-be-compiled so copy/pasting the extracted folders doesn't work.
Below is a short bash script for the quick-and-dirty local installation. It will create symlinks to all files in the CTAN archive extracted.

Go to CTAN find the package required/desired download the zip

unpack it into your preferred directory for additional tex packages (e.g.
$HOME/mytex)

cd to your directory with tex file that needs the
additional packages

run <scriptname> link

try compiling ...


script:
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# CTAN local package installation helper script 
# instruction at the end of file
#
#


case $1 in

    "removelinks")          # remove symlinks
    find . -type l 
    echo
    read  -p "remove all these links? [enter/Ctrl-C]" 
    find . -type l | xargs rm
    exit
    ;;
    
    "link") # symlinks
    read -e -p "enter your tex directory with the unzip CTAN archive: " DIR
    
    ls -x1 $DIR 
    
    echo "
    linking to all files in these directories recursively? [enter/Ctrl-C]"
    read
    
    
    find "$DIR" -type f | while read -r f; 
    do 
     ln -s "$f"
    done
    exit
    ;;
    
esac

cat <<EOF
helper script to quickly install additional or newer tex packages from CTAN without globally installing them.

1. Go to CTAN find the package required/desired
2. download the zip
3. unpack it into your preferred directory for additional tex packages (e.g. $HOME/mytex)
4. cd to your directory with tex file that needs the additional packages
5. run $0 link
6. try compiling ...

The script will  create symlinks to all of the files in the specified tex-directory. 

To remove the links, use $0 removelinks 

EOF


Or you could just install them into $TEXMFHOME.

@cfr echo $TEXMFHOME gives me no output. So, yes, there are ways to do a proper installation, but I did not find a site with a quick guide. This is a recipe for quick-and-dirty installation that will not affect the rest.

It's not a shell variable. kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME.

I unpacked the directories from CTAN into $HOME/texmf, i.e. TEXMFHOME but latex does not compile. Even when creating the symlinks in this directory it does not compile. tkz-euclide has different versions with different commands so if you install the new package systemwide it might conflict with older files. The procedure I added is aimed at avoiding conflict and allowing for testing newer packages without any risk.

If the archive is flat, you have to place the files in specific sub-directories yourself. If there's a tds archive, you should just be able to unpackage it inside the directory and have it work, but it would depend on the package being correctly configured. CTAN used to want tds-compliant packages. These days, they ask for flat. That makes it easier to browse them, but harder to install them :(.
